# tf::TransformListener for Arduino

Tags: ros, arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, Sorry for the mistakes, as English is not my native language. I have a code having the following lines:

```
tf::TransformListener listener;
tf::StampedTransform transform;
while (ros.ok())
{
  try
  {
    listener.lookupTransform("/map", "/base_link", ros::Time(0), transform);
  }
  catch (tf::TransformException ex)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Transform problem -> %s", ex.what());
  }
}
```

I need to handle `tf::TransformException` without `try` and `catch` block because this part of code should be executed on Arduino. Appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408435/tf::transformlistener-for-arduino/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-10-26**:
If your idea is to call TransformListener.lookupTransform() on the Arduino, that is a bad idea. The operation is too heavy for a rs-232 serial link and small cpu unless you have no other choice. Please edit your description and explain more clearly what you think the Arduino needs to do. Publishing sensor data does not require knowing any transforms for the ros system.

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-27**:
Thank you for reply. I have a node that finds robot position, than subscribes to data from topic that contains data from sensors. That data is published by arduino. My thought was to make sure that arduino is started publish data in same time as node, that subscribes to that data is run so no data from sensors is missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the end I solved this problem with modifying not the node that starts on arduino but subscription node that I run on pc. For those who are curious, as far as I could find, there are no way to handle exception without try catch block.

---

Originally posted by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) with karma: 95 on 2022-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0